# Uploading a Json object array to Firestore

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have this nicely ordered yet large Json object Array that follows this structure:

```
{
   "object1":[
      {
         "data1":19.77,
         "data2":-0.953125,
         "data3":-0.265625,
         "id":17231,
         "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.471"
      },
      {
         "data1":19.77,
         "data2":-0.953125,
         "data3":-0.265625,
         "id":17231,
         "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.596"
      },
      {
         "data1":19.77,
         "data2":-0.9609375,
         "data3":-0.2734375,
         "id":17231,
         "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.721"
      }
   ],
   "object2":[
      {
         "data1":19.91,
         "data2":-0.9765625,
         "data3":-0.109375,
         "id":18996,
         "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.681"
      },
      {
         "data1":19.91,
         "data2":-0.9765625,
         "data3":-0.109375,
         "id":18996,
         "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.806"
      },
      {
         "data1":19.91,
         "data2":-1,
         "data3":-0.1171875,
         "id":18996,
         "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:47.931"
      },
      {
         "data1":19.91,
         "data2":-0.96875,
         "data3":-0.1015625,
         "id":18997,
         "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:48.051"
      },
      {
         "data1":19.91,
         "data2":-0.96875,
         "data3":-0.1015625,
         "id":18997,
         "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:48.059"
      },
      {
         "data1":19.91,
         "data2":-0.9765625,
         "data3":-0.109375,
         "id":18997,
         "date":"2021-05-14/08:38:48.176"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I've been trying to upload it to firebase with no success, trying to follow this schema in **Firestore**:

```
Objects
    ├───Object1
    │   ├───[Upload Timestamp]
    │   │   └───Data Array 1
    │   ├───[Upload Timestamp]
    │   │   └───Data Array 2
    │   └───[Upload Timestamp]
    │       └───Data Array 3
    └───Object2
        ├───[Upload Timestamp]
        │   └───Data Array 1
        ├───[Upload Timestamp]
        │   └───Data Array 2
        ├───[Upload Timestamp]
        │   └───Data Array 3
        ├───[Upload Timestamp]
        │   └───Data Array 4
        ├───[Upload Timestamp]
        │   └───Data Array 5
        └───[Upload Timestamp]
            └───Data Array 6
```

I tried to do this with no luck using nested For Loops, Dictionaries and whatnot. So far, I've been only capable of uploading the last Data Array of each object to Firestore.

Is there an way I can properly upload this to Firestore ?

**EDIT: Adding more info about my code**

What I've got:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import json
from itertools import groupby
import datetime
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

json_file_path = "./myfile.json" 

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as j:
    contents = json.loads(j.read())
data = {}
#Sorting my json file
for key, items in groupby(sorted(contents, key = lambda x: (x['id'], x['date'])), key=lambda x: x['id']):  
    data[key] = list(items)

cred = credentials.Certificate("myAppCreds.json")

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
'projectId': "MyProjectID",
})

db = firestore.client()

for keys in data:
    doc_ref = db.collection('Objects').document(keys).collection(d1).document(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    for info in data[keys]:
        doc_ref.set(keys)
```

What happens:

The following entry is created in the Firestore:

```
Objects/object1/19.05.2021/2021-05-19 13:26:03.933868
```

Where the document "2021-05-19 13:26:03.933868" is constantly updated with new values, instead of a new one being created for each new value.
The same happens with `object2`

Comment: Your timestamp is unique to every record inside your object array, so you would have one leaf only under each `[Upload Timestamp]`.

Comment: You are correct, I edited the question.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the interface, but I've managed to create an object on the admin with your object schema. How would I test upload ?

Comment: Basically you need to define an array of maps, inside each `object` node.

Comment: Please edit your question with your upload code that isn't working.

Comment: @Niloct, I edited the question with my code

Comment: There is no `serial` field on the json, you mean the `id` field ? The sort code isn't working (issues TypeError).

Comment: What is the sort criteria ?

Comment: I'm sorry @Niloct, in the original file I'm sorting by 'serial', which serves the same function as the traditional "ID" field, I mande an edit, changing 'serial' to 'ID'

I'm sorting the file first by ID then Date, so I can have all the data from an ID inchronological order

Comment: Then you keep each object order listed as in source ? What if a second object key has a list inside with lower id/date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an working draft, with some remarks:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import json
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

json_file_path = "./myfile.json" 

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as j:
    contents = json.loads(j.read())

# 1. This will be the criteria to sort each inner list
# first by ID, then by date, ascending
def _sort(item):
    return (item['id'], item['date'])

# 2. Sorting my json file lists, in place
for lista in contents.values():
    lista.sort(key=_sort)

cred = credentials.Certificate("myAppCreds.json")

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
'projectId': "MyProjectID",
})    

db = firestore.client()

# Inside the collection Objects, I create a document for each object key,
# Then set the inner list as an inner document, with value equals to the list.
for key, lista in contents.items():
    doc_ref = db.document('Objects/' + key).set({'lista': lista})
```

This won't sort absolutely per id/date, because the objects are sorted individually. You may want to adapt this.

In firebase, I've successfully created the docs running this code.